# Backbone event trigger not being picked up.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, d3.js

The code that I have a question spans multiple pages, so I'll do my best to post what's relevant.

I've created a table using d3, and on click, I'm changing a model. The method that I'm using to change the method is below -

```
    setSelected:()->
         @set
            selected:true
         console.log("SELECTED CALLED")
         @trigger "selected"
         @
```

I know in console that SELECTED CALLED is being printed.

Now, in the initialize function for my view, I've done this -

```
initialize:()->
    @columnHeadings  = @options.columnHeadings
    @columns2Display = @options.columns2Display
    @outerTable = @options.outerTable
    @model.on "selected", @select() 
    @model.on "unselected",@deselect()
```

Now, select looks like this -

```
   select:()=>
        console.log "SELECTED"
        console.log(@model)
```

SELECTED is never printed, which leads me to believe that either Backbone doesn't know which view(there is a view per model, which is also a 'row' view), corresponds to which model, or I'm making a syntax error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this:

```
@model.on "selected",   @select() 
@model.on "unselected", @deselect()
```

you're calling the `@select` and `@deselect` methods and binding their *return values* to the events. The parentheses make them method calls rather than the method references that you want. So just drop the parentheses to bind the method references:

```
@model.on "selected",   @select
@model.on "unselected", @deselect
```